# Instancing a class with an internal constructor

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have a class whose constructor is defined as internal, which means I cannot instantiate it. While that may make sense, I would still like to do it once for debugging and research purposes.

Is it possible to do so with Reflection? I know I can access Private/Internal Members, but can I call an internal constructor?

Or, as the constructor does nothing important, can I use reflection to say "Look, just give me an instance of the class without calling the constructor, I'll do it's work manually"?

Performance and "Stability" is not an issue here, as it's not production code.

**Edit:** Just as clarification: Sadly, I don't control the other assembly and don't have it's source code, I merely try to understand how it works as it's documentation is next to non-existent, but I am supposed to interface with it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

A [FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatterservices.getuninitializedobject.aspx) method exists (Namespace:  System.Runtime.Serialization), it supposedly calls no constructors, if you really want to try out that approach.

Comment: This and Type.GetField()/FieldInfo.SetValue solved my problem.

Comment: @Kenan : risky if the constructor take arguments and operate on those arguments is better use reflection and call it, instead of create an unitialized object and replicate constructor behavoiour from the instance "outside" using reflection.
Seems to me that Tore solution is better.

Answer (score 103):

An alternative would be to nominate the calling assembly as a "friend" assembly.

Simply add this to AssemblyInfo.cs file of the assembly containing the internal constructor:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Calling.Assembly")]
```

---

If you don't have access to the assembly, you can also call the constructor directly (using Reflection):

```
MyClass obj = (MyClass) typeof(MyClass).GetConstructor(
                  BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
                  null, Type.EmptyTypes, null).Invoke(null);
```

Comment: Sadly I don't control the other assembly :(

Comment: Edited my answer to include a solution using reflection

Comment: For some reason, GetContructor returns null, even when experimenting with the BindingFlags. But generally it's an helpful answer, so +1 to that.

Comment: Why 'BindingFlags.Instance'? Is a constructor an instance member?

Answer (score 42):

This is a method derived from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/814238/360211):

```
public static T CreateInstance<T>(params object[] args)
{
    var type = typeof (T);
    var instance = type.Assembly.CreateInstance(
        type.FullName, false,
        BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
        null, args, null, null);
    return (T) instance;
}
```

Example usage (this is a Kinect SDK type that I needed to create for unit tests):

```
DiscreteGestureResult a = CreateInstance<DiscreteGestureResult>(false, false, 0.5f);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to avoid reflection, you can use expressions.
Here is an example of calling a private constructor with a string value.

```
private static Func<string, T> CreateInstanceFunc()
{
    var flags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
    var ctor = typeof(T).GetConstructors(flags).Single(
        ctors =>
        {
            var parameters = ctors.GetParameters();
            return parameters.Length == 1 && parameters[0].ParameterType == typeof(string);
        });
    var value = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "value");
    var body = Expression.New(ctor, value);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<string, T>>(body, value);

    return lambda.Compile();
}
```

Comment: How does this avoid reflection? `typeof(T).GetConstructors(flags).`

Comment: It is only used for discovery one time. lambda.Compile() gives you a function that does not use reflection.

Answer (score 3):

I experienced this same situation a while back and created a small utility I called "InternalsVisibleToInjector".  It uses ILDASM and ILASM to disassemble, modify, and reassemble and assembly with the assembly name of my selection added to the InternalsVisibleTo list for the target assembly.   It worked quite well in my situation.

I have posted the source code (VS 2008 C# WinForm) for the utility here:

http://www.schematrix.com/downloads/InternalsVisibleToInjector.zip

This may not work if the assembly is signed.  Please take all appropriate precautions (i.e. make a backup of the assembly before using this and ensure you are on solid legal ground, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a more practical example. I want to instantiate a `ObjectMaterializedEventArg` from Entity Framework. It looks like this:

```
namespace System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects
{
    /// <summary>EventArgs for the ObjectMaterialized event.</summary>
    public class ObjectMaterializedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        private readonly object _entity;

        internal ObjectMaterializedEventArgs(object entity)
        {
            this._entity = entity;
        }

        /// <summary>Gets the entity object that was created.</summary>
        /// <returns>The entity object that was created.</returns>
        public object Entity
        {
            get { return this._entity; }
        }
    }
}
```

As we we see, this event arg sports only an internal constructor.

To make a unit test to a patient decrypting rule in the software system I work with, we need to instantiate such an object, so I ended up using the *`GetConstructors`* method instead.

```
[Test]
public void EmptyNameAndOfficialIdDoesNotThrow()
{
    var patientDecryptingRule = new PatientDecryptingRule();
    object[] reservation = new object[]
    {
        new Operation
        {
            Status = (int) OperationStatusDataContract.Reservation,
            Patient = new Patient
            {
                Name = null,
                OfficialId = null,
                IsPatientEncrypted = true
            }
        }
    };

    var relevantConstructor = typeof(ObjectMaterializedEventArgs).GetConstructors(
        BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).FirstOrDefault();

    ObjectMaterializedEventArgs objectMaterializedEventArgs =
        (ObjectMaterializedEventArgs) relevantConstructor?.Invoke(reservation);

    patientDecryptingRule.ModifyObjectMaterialized(objectMaterializedEventArgs);
}
```

I use `GetConstructors` here, specifying that the constructor to look for is non public (internal for example) and instance as `bindingflags`, then use `FirsOrDefault`.

Hope this scenario is helpful to some that have trouble getting `GetConstructor` correct. You can use `GetConstructors` instead and filter some more if necessary. Then in the `?.Invoke()` pass in the object array of your parameters.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone stumbles across this again, here's an example of how to raise it via reflection:

```
var args = FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(SizeChangedEventArgs)) as SizeChangedEventArgs;
Debug.Assert(args != null);

var field = typeof(SizeChangedEventArgs).GetField("_previousSize", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
Debug.Assert(field != null);
field.SetValue(args, new Size(0,0));
field = typeof(SizeChangedEventArgs).GetField("_element", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
Debug.Assert(field != null);
field.SetValue(args, GraphicsWrapper);
field = typeof(RoutedEventArgs).GetField("_source", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
Debug.Assert(field != null);
field.SetValue(args, GraphicsWrapper);
field = typeof(RoutedEventArgs).GetField("_routedEvent", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
Debug.Assert(field != null);
field.SetValue(args, SizeChangedEvent);

GraphicsWrapper.RaiseEvent(args);
```

...where the `GraphicsWrapper` is the WPF control you want it raised from.

Comment: B/c...it is impossible to call an internal ctor.  Hence the above example.  Using the FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject() method in the ACCEPTED answer, you bypass this restriction.

Comment: Sorry, I was not paying attention. +1

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to analyse its source code and from that figure out the inner workings.

Comment: @AdamPlocher - lol yourself. The OP clearly states that " I merely try to understand how it works". Reverse engineering the code from IL is, imho, a very viable way of understanding code. I would say that, in order to understand the inner workings of some assembly, it is easier to read the code, than to trying to poke an instance in runtime. So my answer stands, downvoted or not.

Comment: And @AdamPlocher: my 5 year old answer is as old as all the other answers to this question. Hey, even the question is 5 years old! So whats up with that?

Answer (score 0):

`internal` doesn't mean that you can't instantiate it. It just means that only members from the same assembly may call it.

For test purposes you can allow your test assembly to access internals as well using the InternalsVisibleTo attribute. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx

Comment: Er.. what if you want to instantiate it from another assembly.  Then you can't....

Comment: Correct, unless you can use the InternalsVisibleTo. With the update to the question that doesn't seem to be the case, but that was not clear to me from the original wording.