# How to change Resources.resx template

Tags: c#, visual-studio-templates

I want to change Resources.resx template.

Whenever I add a new resource file it should show autogenerated code in following form:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.296
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace ProjectName.Properties
{


/// <summary>
///   A strongly-typed resource class, for looking up localized strings, etc.
/// </summary>
// This class was auto-generated by the StronglyTypedResourceBuilder
// class via a tool like ResGen or Visual Studio.
// To add or remove a member, edit your .ResX file then rerun ResGen
// with the /str option, or rebuild your VS project.
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Resources.Tools.StronglyTypedResourceBuilder", "4.0.0.0")]
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
[global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
**public** class Resources
{

    private static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager resourceMan;

    private static global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo resourceCulture;

    [global::System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1811:AvoidUncalledPrivateCode")]
    **public** Resources()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///   Returns the cached ResourceManager instance used by this class.
    /// </summary>
    [global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    **public** static global::System.Resources.ResourceManager ResourceManager
    {
        get
        {
            if ((resourceMan == null))
            {
                global::System.Resources.ResourceManager temp = new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager("LocBaml1.Properties.Resources", typeof(Resources).Assembly);
                resourceMan = temp;
            }
            return resourceMan;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///   Overrides the current thread's CurrentUICulture property for all
    ///   resource lookups using this strongly typed resource class.
    /// </summary>
    [global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    **public** static global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo Culture
    {
        get
        {
            return resourceCulture;
        }
        set
        {
            resourceCulture = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Here see the bold part (or in between ** **). I need to change internal to public in main template.
How can I do this? Please suggest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

You can change Access Modifier to Public in resource file.

Comment: Great buddy. I didn't notice this. Thanx