# Shimming object that doesn't have constructor

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azureservicebus, shim

I am using 3rd party library, and there is specificly a method that I want to shim.

```
public virtual QueueRuntimeInfo GetQueueRuntimeInfoAsync(string queuePath);
```

This method return `QueueRuntimeInfo` object. Here is the implementation of that class, which there is no constructor:

```cs
public class QueueRuntimeInfo
{
    internal QueueRuntimeInfo(string path)
    {
        this.Path = path;
    }
    public string Path { get; internal set; }
    public long MessageCount { get; internal set; }
}
```

Now, I want to shim `GetQueueRuntimeInfoAsync` method, which return `QueueRuntimeInfo` object, and then I want to set its property manually in my code.

Here is my shim method:

```
ShimManagementClient.AllInstances.GetQueueRuntimeInfoAsyncString = (managementClient, queuePath) =>
        {
            QueueRuntimeInfo queueRuntimeInfo; // what to do?!
            return queueRuntimeInfo;
        };
```

I think I can shim get methods of `QueueRuntimeInfo` class (PathGet and MessageCountGet). But still need to create the object somehow.

Comment: If there's no constructor defined in code, then the compiler generates a parameterless constructor. You can simply do `new QueueRuntimeInfo()`

Comment: Intelisens gives error that `QueueRuntimeInfo` does not contain a constructor that take 0 argurments. Should I ignore this and compile?

Comment: Might it have an `internal` constructor?

Comment: No, I don't think so. It is public class with few properties. it is not partial.

Comment: Is it [this class](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/src/Management/QueueRuntimeInfo.cs)?

Comment: Yes. It is. I removed some unnecessary stuff from it to post.

Comment: Right. As you can clearly see, that's got an `internal` constructor. You are not going to be able to instantiate one of those yourself.

Comment: So does it mean that I won't be able to shim that method in any way?

Comment: If that relies on you instantiating your own `QueueRuntimeInfo`, correct

Comment: Or this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199590/instancing-a-class-with-an-internal-constructor/1199655

Comment: @PatrickMcDonald In my first try It seems that is working. thanks.