# How to mock complex classes from nuget packages in c#?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rfid

I'm relatively new to programming, and I'm not sure how to approach this issue.

My application uses the Impinj OctaneSdk nuget package to connect to and receive tags from multiple RFID readers. The code is relatively complex and involves disconnection handlers to attempt to reconnect in the event of network failures.

The classes provided by the Octane Sdk library for representing readers and tags, have a lot of internal constructers and the like that make mocking using the Moq library difficult, to perform unit tests for specific scenarios.

For example:

The reader objects pass "Tag" objects to an event handler when a tag is read. This "Tag" class has an internal constructer, meaning I can't mock it.

What's the best way to approach mocking a device like this so I can test reconnect/disconnect functionality, etc.

Looking more for an understanding of how an experienced developer would approach this problem, rather than concrete solutions for my particular issue.

I started to implement an interface for all the required classes but it seemed a futile effort due to the amount of custom classes used by the library.

Answer (score 0):

I can't access the documentation for the Octane SDK, so I'm afraid I can't provide concrete suggestions for your specific scenario. However, in general terms:

- Consider what it is that you want to test. If your main interest is to test your business logic that is triggered by the external dependency, you can encapsulate the SDK within a higher-level interface of your own design, and mock / fake that interface instead of the SDK. (This is probably good practice anyway). The way I approach this is to imagine that I want to swap out the current SDK for an equivalent one from a different supplier, and think of the common business events, triggers, and types that would be common to all RFID libraries.
- If you need to test your wrapper around the SDK, these are likely to be complex tests. Consider whether they will provide enough value to justify the time to create and maintain them. If there's any asynchrony involved, or lots of mocking, it might take a lot of effort to prevent the tests being [brittle](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189805/brittle-unit-tests-due-to-need-for-excessive-mocking).
- If you want to instantiate a `Tag` object despite its internal constructor, check out [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30728269/260213).

For lots of general advice about unit testing in general, including advanced scenarios, the book [Unit Testing Principles, Practices, and Patterns](https://www.manning.com/books/unit-testing) is a great resource. Personally, I don't entirely agree with the author on all points, but it will at the very least get you thinking about what makes for a good unit test.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. I'll give that book a read. I wrote my first unit test this week, so a starting point about what makes a good unit test is exactly what I need!